# Select a post by its metadata found in the wp_postmeta table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, elasticsearch

How do I select a post by its metadata found in the `wp_postmeta` table? Preferably using ElasticPress.

```
new WP_Query( array(
    's'             => 'meta search phrase',
    'search_fields' => array(
        'post_title',
        'post_content',
        'post_excerpt',
        'meta' => array( 'meta_key_1', 'meta_key_2' ),
    ),

) );
```

I found this example from the [ElasticPress documentation](https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress), but I am not sure that this is querying the correct table (wp_postmeta), and I also want to check if a particular value is in post meta value, not the post meta key...

EDIT:

I've tried this below, but am not getting anything returned with this query. I'm setting `'key' => 'foo_listing_syndication',` and `'value' => $term,` where `$term` is the search text and `foo_listing_syndication` is the key in the `meta_key` column of the `wp_postmeta` table. Would this not be correct? See screenshot of the `wp_postmeta` table. The `$term` I am trying to search for is found the in `meta_value` column.

```
$query = new \WP_Query([
     ...
    's'             => $term,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'foo_listing_syndication',
            'value' => $term,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
     ),
]);
```

[image]

Comment: You should see this article on multiple ways to use the meta query: https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-query-posts-with-meta-keys-values-in-wordpress/

Comment: @WPZA thanks, I've tried that, but am not getting anything returned with that query. I'm setting `'key'   => 'foo_listing_syndication',` and `'value' => $term,` where `$term` is the search text and `foo_listing_syndication` is the key in the `meta_key` column of the `wp_postmeta` table. Would this not be correct? I'm new to WordPress

Comment: @WPZA I've updated my question to show these changes you suggested

Comment: Do you get any results if you manually type whatever $term is? Also for the key try `_foo_listing_syndication` to see what happens.

Comment: @WPZA no I don't get any results that way either. And I just tried `_foo_listing_syndication` without luck. I've also tried switching the `compare` to `LIKE`, but so far it isn't working either

Comment: From https://github.com/10up/ElasticPress it mentions an example in the `meta_query` section. Could you use this and forget the use of `$term` for the time being? Also try with a different meta key, as there mightn't be anything matching for the `foo_listing_syndication`;

Comment: @WPZA I finally figured it out, you cannot have both `'s' => $term,` and `'meta_query' => array(` in the same `WP_Query`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had an idea for you if you're not using a pagination: you could do `if get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'foo_listing_syndication' ) == $term ) :` inside your query to only show posts with this key?